# C# code to change URL of an image in UpdateProgress

Tags: c#, asp.net, updateprogress

I am trying to create a User ID availability check for new users while registering in a website.

My code looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="23px" ImageUrl="~/Images/x_mark_red.png" Width="24px" />
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Check" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to write a C# code to change the image URL, and this is for changing the image from Spinning to Green check mark or to Red X Mark.

Any ideas please?

Best regards

Comment: the progressbar runs on the client you have to use javascript to do this not c#

Comment: So there is no way to display that image using C#?

Comment: Nope there isn't you have to use javascript. But honestly I would just use a gif animation...

Comment: Yes, That's what i did finally.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, initially before the actual id check is done, I would set the Image1 url to blank. So I would have a line like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="23px" ImageUrl="" Width="24px" />
```

Then in your code-behind you can define an event handler to do the work and update the image url:

```
public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bool isIdAvailable = SomeFunction() - Do whatever you need to determine whether userId is available.

   Image1.ImageUrl = (isIdAvailable) ? 
      "~/Images/green-check-mark.png" : "~/Images/x_mark_red.png";
}
```

Comment: THe problem is in that case ( WHen the user click on Check Button. it will show Spinning gif... 
THen the C# code will check the USer ID. your code will refresh the page at the initial click

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for user availability on Check button click,
write following code in Button2_Click handler:

```
if (UserIdIsAvailable()) // your check for user id availability here
{
  Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/available.png";
}
```

Also make sure you don't overwrite ImageUrl on Page_Load.

In case if you are checking for user availability on client using ajax requests, you need to change image using javascript.

Comment: Yes but I am checking the user ID availability from DB , using C# code. I just need a C# code to update the image only without refreshing the whole page.